# Couldn't locate an error message in Selenium to assert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I was trying to write tests to validate mandatory fields. One of the fields is "Document ID". I found its XPath and checked in firefox and chrome and it worked. When I used the same in the script, I'm getting NoSuchElementException. The code of the element is in:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 edit-view-row-item">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 label" data-label="LBL_RESUME_ID">
Document ID:
<span class="required">*</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 edit-view-field " field="resume_id" 
type="varchar">
<input id="resume_id" type="text" title="" value="" maxlength="255" size="30" 
 name="resume_id" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<label>
<input id="document_type_c" type="radio" title="" checked="checked" 
value="Passport" name="document_type_c" tabindex="0">
Passport
</label>
<label>
<input id="document_type_c" type="radio" title="" value="DriversLicense" 
name="document_type_c" tabindex="0">
Driver's License
</label>
<label>
<input id="document_type_c" type="radio" title="" value="EAD" 
name="document_type_c" tabindex="0">
EAD Copy
</label>
<label>
<input id="document_type_c" type="radio" title="" value="State_ID" 
name="document_type_c" tabindex="0">
State ID
</label>
<label>
<input id="document_type_c" type="radio" title="" value="Others" 
name="document_type_c" tabindex="0">
Others
</label>
<div class="required validation-message">Missing required field: Document 
ID</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The XPaths I tried:

```
//input[@id='resume_id']/../div
//input[@value='Others']/../following-sibling::div
```

The code I tried:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement dIdErrorMessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@id='resume_id']/../div")));

WebElement dIdErrorMessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@value='Others']/../following-sibling::div")));

String validityMessage = dIdErrorMessage.getText();
Assert.assertEquals("Missing required field: Document ID", validityMessage);
```

Comment: Did you try to [wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for required element to appear in DOM?

Comment: Post the different code attempts you tried. Is the element in an IFRAME? Did you try a wait as Andersson suggested?

Comment: Yes. I did wait for the visibility of the element @Andersson. Still getting the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: No. The element is not in a frame @JeffC.

Comment: @learningQA , are you sure? if you've applied wait for visibility and it failed you should get `TimeoutException`, not `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Sorry. I applied the wait and got TimeOutException.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to verify? From your question and locators, it's not clear.

Comment: I was trying to verify the error message "Missing required field: Document ID
".

Answer (score 0):

Try with directly checking the text inside element:

> //div[text()[normalize-space()='Document ID:']]

If this is not a solution, please specify which element or text you wish to validate.